# How do I do coordination between multiple application instances?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, distributed, apache-curator

Need help in deciding what frameworks I can use in this scenario. I'm exploring Zookeeper, but not completely sure on how to solution this usecase.

**background :**

1. Say there is application that connects to a streaming source(Kafka or Activemq etc) and writes messages that were processed from the stream
   to a file.
2. This application is deployed as 4 instances.Each instance is processing messages and writing to file that were processed in last 1 hr.
3. Each instance creates a file that stores messages that it processed last 1 
    hour. example -filename is servername_8.00 for messages processed from 8-9
4. Requirement is to transfer all the files that were created last 1 hour if every instance created  a file in that window and also send only one consolidated file which lists all the 4 file names and
   number of records.

**what i'm looking for** :
 1. How do I make sure application instances know if other instances also created files and if every instance created then only they should transmit file 
 2. whatever instance sending, consolidated file should know what was transmitted.

**what frameworks I can use  to solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use ZooKeeper for this. I would use Apache Curator as well (note: I'm the main author of Curator).

Do all the instances share a file server? i.e. can each instance see all of the created files? If so, you can nominate a leader using ZooKeeper/Curator and only the leader does all of the work. You can see sample leader election code here: https://github.com/apache/curator/tree/master/curator-examples/src/main/java/leader

If the instances do not share a file server, you could still use ZooKeeper to coordinate the writing of the shared file. You'd again nominate a leader who exposes an API of some kind that all the instances can write to and the leader creates the shared file.

You also might find the Curator barrier recipes useful: http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/double-barrier.html and http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/barrier.html

You'd have to give a lot more detail on your use case if you want a more detail design.